# Boolean + Particles to make randomly distributed pores throughout a mesh

Tags: modifiers, particles

I am looking to make a random distribution of pores throughout a mesh. The most straight forward approach (in my mind) is to model a few random pore shapes in a collection, use emitter to randomly distribute the collection as particles in the volume of interest, then perform the boolean operation to cut the particles away, leaving voids in the solid. Is this possible? If not, is there an efficient way to achieve this effect?